# Подмена содержимого SPAN

Tags: jquery, javascript

**Есть блок:**

```
<div>  
Наша первая цена <span class="jeuro">1500< /span>  
<br />  
Наша вторая цена <span class="jeuro">230,78< /span>  
</div>
```

**Надо:**

1. Достать содержимое каждого SPAN с классом jeuro
2. Умножить каждое полученное значение на курс (предположим - 41,3)
3. Вывести получившиеся значения на прежних местах

Помогите чем можете ;)
Совсем не разбираюсь в Java Script

Comment: На будущее - чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 4):

```
var kurs = 41.19;
$('.jeuro').each(function(){
   var value = $(this).html();
   value = parseFloat(value,10)*kurs;
   $(this).html(value); 
});
```

Как-то так

Comment: первое значение точно по второму какой то брак (как будто в прогрессии) =(  
вот так вроде работает но мне кажется что из за незнания языка я криво это сделал = )
 
$(document).ready(  
  function(){  
  $(".jeuro").each(function () {  
  var value = $(this).html()*41.19;  
  $(this).html(value);  
});
});

Comment: @Никита_ST все практически ок:

    $(function(){  
      $(".jeuro").each(function() {  
        var $el = $(this);
        var value = $el.html()*41.19;  
        $el.html(value);  
      });
    });

Хотя @Barton правильно делает, нужно еще парсить значение т.к. оно не всегда валидно и, если, например, html элемента будет "121233,232", то умножив его на любое число - получим NaN

Answer (score 3):

1. Лучше использовать метод **.text()**, т.к. может затесаться какой-нибудь тэг
2. По второму, как вы сказали "бардак"  потому, что у вас запятая, а для вычислений нужна точка.
3. В общем, [смотрим вариант тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/TK3H2/)

P.S. Я там сделал округление до сотых. Если не надо, то убирайте.

Comment: lol, так под бардаком подразумевался NaN :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, так мне это объяснять не надо. Я писал, отвечая на комментарий ТС выше.

Comment: @Deonis - я это понял, с чего вы взяли что это камень в ваш огород?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, финал рабочего дня, усталость... ))

Answer (score 2):

Зачем `.each()`? почему бы не использовать `.text()`?

```
$(".jeuro").text(function(i, text){
   $(this).text(text*41.19); 
});
```

только вместо десятичной запятой используйте десятичную точку

и ещё в таких случаях рекомендуется использовать [jQuery.single](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/76-bytes-for-faster-jquery/)

- [.text( function(index, text))](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

Comment: @Spectre - потому-что использования text нифига не очевидно. Как говориться - код нужно стараться писать так, что-бы его можно было читать как рассказ. Так вот - первый выозов text нифига не читается, имхо :)

Comment: >Как говориться - код нужно стараться писать так, что-бы его можно было читать как рассказ

это где же такое говориться? в спецификации языка COBOL?

а как помне, вполне очевидный функциональный подход, если сразу представить, что `$(".jeuro")` - это коллекция элементов, а не одиночный объект

или использование `map`, `grep` и т.п. тоже неочевидно и нужно использовать `each`?

Comment: @Spectre - эти правила придумал не я и, давайте на чистоту - как много "разработчиков", с ходу разберутся? Если вы, что вряд-ли, но тем не менее, не знаете ответа, то - не много :) ( вернее разберутся, но полезут в документацию, гугл и т.д. )

Comment: опять же имхо, но если использовать тот или иной фреймворк/библиотеку, то надо иметь представления о его/её возможностях, хотя бы в общих чертах. На примере jQuery это то, что многие методы, выступающие в роли сеттера, позволяют принимать в качестве аргумента функцию, которая будет применена ко всем элементам коллекции

Comment: @Spectre если в вашей работе такие люди не редкость, то я могу вам только позавидовать :)